# scrapy: spider quits without error messages before all requests yielded

Tags: python, scrapy

If there are many requests in scheduler, would scheduler reject more requests to be added?

I met a very tricky question. I am trying to scrape a forum with all posts and comments. The problem is scrapy seems never finish it jobs and quits without error messages. I am wondering if I yielded too many requests so that scrapy stopped yielding new requests and just quit.

But I could not find documentation says that scrapy will quit if too many requests in schedular. Here is my code:
https://github.com/spacegoing/sentiment_mqd/blob/a46b59866e8f0a888b43aba6df0481a03136cf21/guba_spiders/guba_spiders/spiders/guba_spider.py#L217

The strange thing is that scrapy seems can only scrape 22 pages. If I start from page 1, it will stop at page 21. If I start from page 21, then it will stop at page 41.... There is no exception raised and scraped results are desired outputs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If that won't expose any sensitive info from your side, do you mind sharing at least the last few (50~100?) lines of the job log?
_The problem is scrapy seems never finish it jobs and quits without error messages._ specifically, I'm unsure whether that's: 1. Scrapy ended execution unexpectedly, or 2. Scrapy finished normally but the scraped results are not as expected (_never finish it jobs_).

Comment: @starrify You are very welcome. The strange thing is that scrapy seems can only scrape 22 pages. If I start from page 1, it will stops at page 21. If I start from page 21, then it will stop at page 41.... There is no exception raised and scraped results are desired outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1.

The code on GitHub you shared at `a46b598` is probably not the exact version you have locally for the sample jobs. E.g. I haven't observed any line for the log lines like `<timestamp> [guba] INFO: <url>`.
But, well, I assumed there's no too significant difference.

#### 2.

It's suggested to have the log level configured to DEBUG when you encounter any issue.

#### 3.

If you've got the log level configured to DEBUG, you'd probably see something like this:

`2018-10-26 15:25:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Discarding <GET http://guba.eastmoney.com/topic,600000_22.html>: max redirections reached`

Some more lines: https://gist.github.com/starrify/b2483f0ed822a02d238cdf9d32dfa60e

That happens because you're passing the full `response.meta` dict to the following requests ([related code](https://github.com/spacegoing/sentiment_mqd/blob/a46b59866e8f0a888b43aba6df0481a03136cf21/guba_spiders/guba_spiders/spiders/guba_spider.py#L222)), and Scrapy's `RedirectMiddleware` relies on some meta values (e.g. "redirect_times" and "redirect_ttl") to perform the check.

And the solution is simple: pass only the values you need into `next_request.meta`.

#### 4.

It's also observed that you're trying to rotate the user agent strings, possibly for avoiding web crawl bans. But there's no other action taken. That would make your requests fishy still, because:

- Scrapy's cookie management is enabled by default, which would use a same cookie jar for all your requests.
- All your requests come from a same source IP address.

Thus I'm unsure whether it's good enough for you to scrape the whole site properly, especially when you're not throttling the requests.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I think point 3 is exactly the problem. However I've edited my code as you said by only taking fields I need. The spider still stopped on 20 requests. Would you please take another look? Many thanks! https://github.com/spacegoing/sentiment_mqd/blob/43c14161286f8b3b040466a59f57be3287137529/guba_spiders/guba_spiders/spiders/guba_spider.py#L125

Comment: @spacegoing Looks like you're not filtering out the right meta keys in [your code](https://github.com/spacegoing/sentiment_mqd/blob/43c14161286f8b3b040466a59f57be3287137529/guba_spiders/guba_spiders/spiders/guba_spider.py#L58). Please check my note #3 above for the meta keys related to redirection.